# Register same custom styles to multiple block types in gutenberg

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add some styles to more than one block type.

At the moment I'm doing this for every block type like this and change only the part `'core/paragraph'` to `'core/heading'` for example.

Is there any way to do this for more than one block at the same time?

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle(
'core/paragraph',
[
    {
        name: 'default',
        label: 'Default',
        isDefault: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'lead',
        label: 'Lead',
    },
    {
        name: 'subline',
        label: 'Subline',
    },
]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know names of the blocks you want to add your styles to, you can use `registerBlockStyle()` in a `forEach()` loop to mass register multiple styles to multiple blocks, eg:

```
const blocks = ["core/quote", "core/heading", "core/paragraph"]; //etc..

const styles = [
    {
        name: 'default',
        label: 'Default',
        isDefault: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'lead',
        label: 'Lead',
    },
    {
        name: 'subline',
        label: 'Subline',
    }
];

// Loop through each block and register all custom styles in one go..
blocks.forEach(function(blocks) {
    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle(blocks, [...styles]);
});
```

To find the names of all currently registered blocks, use:

```
wp.blocks.getBlockTypes().map(block => block.name);
```

*Even though you could apply your styles to every block, please use it sparingly only on required blocks - not every block all at once..*